# Using dplyr to group and transpose

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, finance

I have a financial dataset.

```
dat = data.frame(Fundemental = rep(c("EPS", "ROE"), 2), 
Dates = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-02-02"), 
Value = rnorm(4))
##
   Fundemental      Dates      Value
 1         EPS 2019-01-01  2.0685114
 2         ROE 2019-01-01 -0.4700701
 3         EPS 2019-02-02  0.3254684
 4         ROE 2019-02-02 -0.6270476
```

Is there a quick way in dplyr to group the data frame by date so the data.frame has column names c(Dates, Value, ROE, EPS) and looks something like this.

```
         Dates       EPS Value   ROE Value
 1       2019-01-01  2.0685114   0.3254684    
 2       2019-02-02 -0.4700701   0.6270046
```

I wrote some code using the Map function, but I really feel like it's over kill! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `tidyr::spread`, `dat %>%
  spread(Fundemental, Value)` or any of the options from the marked link.

Comment: I think it's worth emphasising that [the `tidyr::spread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25023569/3246758) solution is more current than the others (esp. for someone tagging `tidyverse`) :)

Comment: thank you! the reshape solution was not very good with multivariables. spread worked great!!